# There is a way to make jslint show a warning or an error when console is used?

Tags: javascript, jslint

I know that many people would prefer to ignore that warning, but here are some reasons because I think it should be a good idea:

- It's just a global var, like others, and I don't want to use it without explicitly declaring it as one of the /* globals */
- There are some jslint options (like *browser* or *devel*) which porpuse is to allow the implicit use of globals like *document*, *window* and *console* without warnings, so the use of *console* shouldn't be allowed by default (note that *document* and  *window* are not allowed by default)
- I use *console* very often for debugging, but I don't want to accidentally include those console.log lines in production, so it would be really useful to rely on jslint to help me to remember to remove those lines.

So, I thought that the default jslint behavior was to warn when *console* is used, but apparently it isn't. What do you think? It is a bug? There is a way to change that behavior?

Comment: Can't you just grep your code?

Comment: Not a bug. ;^) As @suish says, by default JSLint *does* let you know where you used `console`. Can you provide a simplest-case code example that behaves "incorrectly" when run on [jslint.com](http://jslint.com)? I'm not a huge fan of [monkeypatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), but what suish suggests is a way to grenade the problem without really fixing it (which can be useful!).

Comment: You're right @ruffin. I tried in jslint.com and it throws an error.
It seems that the bug is in my node command line tool node-jslint 0.6.6. 
It makes sense considering the number of the version. I will report the bug.
Why don't you write this comment as an answer? I would choose it as the best answer.

Comment: I've just opened a new issue in github https://github.com/reid/node-jslint/issues/123.

Comment: Ha, sure! Added an answer. If the issue gets closed without a resolution, though, feel free to comment that answer so I can take another look. That's interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bug. ;^) As @suish says, by default JSLint does let you know where you used `console`. Can you provide a simplest-case code example that behaves "incorrectly" when run on [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com)? I'm not a huge fan of [monkeypatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch), but what suish suggests is a way to grenade the problem without really fixing it (which can be useful!).

That's interesting if the node package doesn't work correctly -- it does seem to have [a very recent version of JSLint](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint/blob/master/lib/jslint-latest.js#L2). Perhaps it's setting default JSLint directives somewhere?

Comment: I've just received a response on the issue. He explained the problem is that node-jslint sets option node=true by default. Which kind of makes sense given the prefix in the name of the tool haha.

Answer (score 1):

simply use `console.log` without global variable.and turn off `devel` then you can easily find where they are.

In addition, If you put these on the top of your code when you publish your code.console.log would be disabled even if your product code accidentally contains `console.log`

```
var console = {};
console.log = function(){};
window.console = console;
```